# Keep a shared library from using its own exports

Tags: c++

Good evening,

I have a library that imports another library which exports a function, lets call it foo(). I want my library to serve as a wrapper for the other library. That means, I want my library to export a function foo() which internally calls the function foo() from the other library. Something like this:

```
myfoo.hpp:

__attribute__((visibility("default"))) void foo();  //my foo() export

myfoo.cpp:

#include "myfoo.hpp"
#include "wrapperfoo.hpp"

void foo()
{
   wrapperfoo();
}

wrapperfoo.cpp:

#include "wrapperfoo.hpp"
#include "theotherapifoo.hpp"

void wrapperfoo()
{
   ::foo();  //PROBLEM!! This seems to call my own exported foo from myfoo.hpp!!!
}
```

The problem is that both dynamic libraries get linked into the executable and my wrapperfunction seems to recursively call my own exported foo function over and over despite wrapperfoo.cpp not including myfoo.hpp!

What can I do to prevent this from happening and access the other libraries foo()?

Comment: Aren't you flagrantly violating the One Definition Rule? You can't give two functions the same name like that. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question because I'm very tired.

Comment: By the looks of it, the code ends up in an inifinite call loop. Also why does the "myfoo" object call wrapper code? Wasn't that supposed to be the actual implementation?

Comment: I think you have to link the other library at runtime. I'm not aware of the functions to use, but there should be a way to link libraries at runtime and query pointers to specific functions in the loaded library. But there could be some problems while resolving the dependencies of the loaded library if you are using this solution. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: There is someone who basically wants an "enriched" version of the other library that does some more debugging stuff but shall reuse the headers of the other api (that means I'm only replacing the actual .so with my own version).

Comment: So I ended up renaming __attribute__((visibility("default"))) void foo();  export   to   __attribute__((visibility("default"))) void foo_wrap();     ,   then use #defines in the wrapper library import header to "name" it back to foo. Thats the best solution that came to my mind without dynamic linking.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround would be to dynamically link the library using `dlopen()` or similar.

```cxx
#include <cstring>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdexcept>

struct OriginalLibrary {
    using FunPtr = void(*)();
    OriginalLibrary()
        : m_lib([] {
                if (void * const lib = dlopen("libdl.so", RTLD_NOW))
                    return lib;
                throw std::runtime_error(dlerror());
            }())
        , m_foo(getFunSym("foo"))
    {}
    ~OriginalLibrary() noexcept { dlclose(m_lib); }

    FunPtr getFunSym(char const * const name) {
        if (void * const sym = dlsym(m_lib, name)) {
            FunPtr f;
            // Assuming function and data pointers are of
            // same size and binary-compatible on your arch:
            std::memcpy(&f, &sym, sizeof(f));
            return f;
        }
        throw std::runtime_error(dlerror());
    }

    void * const m_lib;
    void (* m_foo)();
};

// WARNING! Global symbol! (you might want to solve this in some other manner)
OriginalLibrary original;

void foo() { return original.m_foo(); }
```